# Can i crete Javascript to this HTML?(only a part of code)

Tags: javascript, html, css

i dont know the javascript at all and i would need help if it is possible to crete hamburger javascript to this code

```
<header>
        <div class="sub-cont">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/89922971?s=280&v=4" alt=""
                    class="logo"></a>
            <h3><a href="index.html"> SPŠ Mladá Boleslav</h3></a>
            <div class="ham">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
            <ul class="head">
                <li class="bruh">Aktuality<ul class="idk">
                        <li>Něco</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>O škole</li>
                <li>Pro uchazeče</li>
                <li>Pro žáky a rodiče</li>
                <li>Kontakty</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="under-icons">
                <div class="main-icons">
                    <a href="https://www.strava.cz/strava/"><img
                            src="https://www.strava.cz/Strava/Obsah/mobil/obrazky/stravacz_ikona_velka.png"
                            class="icon2" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="https://www.skolaonline.cz/Aktuality.aspx"><img src="skolaonline.jpg" class="icon"
                            alt=""></a>
                </div>
                <div class="main-icons2">
                    <i style="font-size:24px; color: red;" class="fa"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/@sps-mb">
                            &#xf16a;</a></i>
                    <i style="font-size:24px; " class="fa"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/spsmb.cz/">
                            &#xf09a;</a></i>
                    <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa"><a href="https://github.com/SPSMB"> &#xf09b;</a></i>
                </div>
            </div>
    </header>
```

So it would show the sub-cont normally but head and under-icons only when i click the hamburger menu. If it is needed to change the html to make it work i am asking for help please. It is a project to school, and i need to make it work.

I did not tried anything because i dont know JAvascript so i wanted to ask at first if it is even possible to create one for this html code and if someone could provide it please

Comment: Nobody here will write the code for you. Please take the tour here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/tour
Read also "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
and How do I ask a good question? : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

then, you'll find how to get started with javascript : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript

Comment: @tatactic ok but it is possible to write javascript for this?

Comment: Did my answer answers your question? If yes, you can accept it.

Comment: @André  well yes but a different things though. Chatgpt explained it to me pretty a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with JavaScript. Before I knew JavaScript I would often look at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp) for code snippets that perform the functions I need.
You can find the code [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp), just copy to your website and modify to your needs:
HTML

```
 <!-- Load an icon library to show a hamburger menu (bars) on small screens -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

JavaScript

```
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```